# What's the difference between MIPS and RISC?

Tags: mips

It says that MIPS is a type of RISC. What is the history? Are both formats / instruction models / programming models, how to tell MIPS from RISC? Is RISC a wider concept?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. RISC is a wider concept. MIPS is RISC (Reduced Instruction Set Chip) architecture. Reduced (RISC) architectures tend to be simpler and have a small number of operations. Complex (CISC) architectures like x86 have more instructions, some of which take the place of a sequence of RISC instructions.

Comment: modern x86 architecture nowadays is very much RISC type

Answer (score 5):

From the [mips](/questions/tagged/mips) [taginfo page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mips/info):

> MIPS is a common RISC (Reduced Instruction Set Computer) ISA
>   (Instruction Set Architecture), one of the first of its kind.
>   Currently, MIPS can refer to both a hardware implementation of the ISA
>   and the assembly language itself.